# Finding a polynomial function that runs through a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra

If there a few points, let say, (1, p), (2, q), and (3, r) where `p, q, r` are all arbitrary constants, is it possible to construct a polynomial (`a + bt + ct^2)` whose graphs fits those points? Do the points actually matter (are all points possible or only a few?)

I'm trying to solve this using linear methods, but I'm stuck and can't find a way. What I have realized is that `f(t) = a + bt + ct^2` and so `f(1) = a + b + c = p` and `f(2) = a + 2b + 4c = q` and `f(3) = a + 3b + 9c = r` but I don't know where to go from there

So, I have this matrix set up:

```
| 1 1 1 p |
| 1 2 4 q |
| 1 3 9 r |
```

Comment: Yes, there are many possibilities for this to happen.  If you want to determine the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, then you need to set up the augmented matrix and determine the variables.

Comment: I guess what I looking for is a way to solve these equations (with any kinds of constraints) with Gaussian Elimination. I don't understand how to solve the matrix when I have 3 equations and 4 variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition) page on the Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial will help out.

It will work no matter what values of $a,b$ and $c$ you choose, and is unique as well.

EDIT to provide details.

As the commenters have said, you do indeed have a matrix equation to solve, or an augmented matrix to play with:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &| & p \\
1 & 2 & 4 &| & q \\
1 & 3 & 9 &| & r
\end{pmatrix},$$
where you only have 3 equations in 3 unknowns, leading to a unique solution provided all $x$-values are distinct. Now you can use elementary row operations to transform this augmented matrix into (I believe, I only checked $f(1)$)

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &| & -p -3q +r \\
0 & 1 & 0 &| & 7/2p +4q -3/2r \\
0 & 0 & 1 &| & -3/2p -q +1/2r
\end{pmatrix}.$$

There is most likely an error in my solution, so take with a grain of salt. However, the idea is valid: you are given enough information to determine $a, b,$ and $c$.

Note that this is a minimally elementary solution. By this I mean that with only the information you've worked out, you can get a solution. If I recall from my Numerical Methods class, it is by no means an efficient way to solve this problem, but it is very transparent.

Comment: Is this possible with Gaussian Elimination?

Answer (score 0):

By simple elimination technique, you should arrive to
$a = 4 r - 3 q$
$b = 4 q - 4 r$
$c = r - q$